# maintaining credentials for wcf binding over the life of my app

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WPF client app that uses a WCF service hosted in IIS (using `BasicHTTPBinding`).  i'm trying to move to SSL and basic auth because we have users who will use the app on off-domain pc's.  i have a class that builds and returns an instance of the service object (we'll call it ProxyGenerator), and stores username (string) and password (securestring).  flow goes from

1. Login window, has textbox, passwordbox, and login button.  login button creates the proxygenerator object, sets it's username and password, and passes it (via parameterized thread start) to:
2. Main window, contains user interface to do Real Work® and calls `ProxyGenerator.GetProxy()` to get a proxy to use.

this seems to work ok, until we get to:

  3.  usercontrol1 (embedded in Main window) which needs access to the proxy.

what would be the ideal way to deal with this, given the need for off-domain access?  ideally, everyone would be on-domain and i could just use windows authentication through iis (and thus just get user credentials from the system whenever i needed them.  this is actually how it works now.).

note: this is a "just get it working now, fix it later" project at the moment.  also, i'm kinda new at this service stuff, so proxy may be the wrong word, or i may be using it in the wrong context.

```
public class ProxyGenerator
{

    public string username;
    public SecureString password;
    public string endpoint;

    private TestingService.ServiceClient _proxy = null;

    public ProxyGenerator(string uname, SecureString pword)
    {
        username = uname;
        password = pword;

        endpoint = "insert endpoint here"

    }

    public TestingService.ServiceClient GetProxy()
    {
        _proxy = new ServiceClient(endpoint);
        _proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        _proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        return _proxy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's what i did, for anyone who ends up here one day.  i know i hate unanswered questions!

first, i had to get a grasp of what was actually happening, and realize that the application startup was not what it should have been.  app.xaml/cs would call loginwindow, loginwindow would ask for credentials, then instantiate(? is that the right word) the above class with the credentials.  it would then create a new thread to load MainWindow and pass the instance of the class through to it.  the thread would call mainwindow constructor with the instance of the class and the program would start.  this was all done so there could be a little animation on the login window while you wait.

what i did was make a new class that inherited Window and extended it with a SetProxyGenerator() method and a ProxyGenerator object to use.  i went through and changed all of my data viewing/requesting windows to inherit the new class.  then i changed the flow of the program to load the main window first and in the constructor, call a different, simpler login window.  build the proxy generator with the information, and now i just pass it to any new window i make.  everything is on the same thread now and functional.

no idea why the startup was made so complicated...

maybe next time you guys can answer my question. :)